# Explanation /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, homebrew

I would like to understand exactly what this command does. I know this command installs homebrew on macOS, but I would like to understand the meaning of the syntax:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

For example:

/bin/bash is the path to the bash folder

what about the other parts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- `/bin/bash` executes a new instance of bash
- `-c` passes one or several commands to be executed
- `$(...)` runs the command within `()` and returns its result (Command Substitution)
- `curl ...` gets the file specified in the URL

So basically `bash` gets called to execute the content of the file fetched by `curl`.

Some things you may try to understand this in more detail

- run `curl ...` to see what `curl` returns, or `curl ... | less` to examine it in more detail
- run `/bin/bash -c 'echo "Welcome to bash"'`
- read `man bash` and `man curl`

Comment: Notably, this is a very memory intensive way of achieving the desired effect (running the script pointed to by the URL).  If you are already running in bash, you can instead do `bash <(curl ...)` to get the same effect without having to store the whole script in memory (it will save the output from the bit in `<(...)` to a temporary file and then pipe that to stdin for the instance of `bash` being invoked).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn You've got it the wrong way round: `<(…)` doesn't usually create a temporary file. And it doesn't pass the data to bash's stdin but rather as a file argument that points to a special `/dev/fd` file representing a pipe. You *could* alternatively pipe into bash's stdin, using the regular pipe syntax, by passing the `-s` option.

Answer (score 6):

I want to add that if you're security conscious, you should never cut-n-paste such a command from a web site to run on your computer like that.

The HomeBrew project is a well-known and respected piece of software so I'm not saying that there is anything inherently wrong with installing it. However, their web site could be compromised in the future, where this command no longer performs as intended.

Also in general it is a good idea to not learn a habit of just cut-n-pasting commands like this to install software.

A security conscious way of handling this situation would be to download the `install.sh` file to your computer first. Then you need to read it through and understand what it does - and only then run it. Note that it is not a good idea to merely browse the `install.sh` file in a browser to determine that it is okay, as it is actually possible for a malicious server to detect whether or not you're browsing the script in a browser, or actually downloading to immediately execute it - and they could swap out the contents underneath you.

The main problem here is ofcourse that few people will know how to read and understand shell scripts.

Comment: Eh. If the Homebrew website is compromised then so are presumably its formulas. It isn't practical to read the source code of every software you install.

Comment: Perhaps - perhaps not. Even though you have only guarded against one potential problem out of many, that is at least one less to worry about. And yes, it isn't practical to read the source code of every software you install - everyone agrees about that. That's why I think it would be a good idea for HomeBrew to be even better at ensuring that malicious software doesn't get through. For example when you're installing something with HomeBrew, the resources that are fetched (for example source tar balls) are integrity checks by means of a SHA hash. If the dependency has changed, then you will

Comment: know it. Imagine if the formulae themselves were signed using public key cryptography, so that you could very that the formulae themselves were at least signed by a trusted approver at the HomeBrew project. Similar to how programs installed through the App Store are signed by Apple, so that you know that they at least run some automatized checks on it, and possibly manually reviewed some parts of the functionality. These things are not perfect, but if you look at package managers on other systems, you'll find that a lot of effort went into this.

Comment: As mentioned, HomeBrew is a particular "bad example" - but it is more about not getting into the habit of just pasting whatever installation string that you find on any web site. Other types of software exist that try to make it easy for user's to install in a similar way - but they might not be hosting their web site on GitHub, but rather on something that it not as secure. Better to be in the habit of checking what exactly you're executing. I know that when you get the program installed, even if you have checked the installer shell script, the program might itself be malicious, so nothing

Comment: is perfect......

Comment: @KonradRudolph Also, it is *not* immediately apparent that the OP's command is running the *homebrew* installation script.  It is running a script downloaded from a website which is *not* immediately apparent that it is part of GitHub where the homebrew project is / might be located. (Is githubusercontent.com controlled by the same party as github.com?) Actually, this entire workflow is full of opportunities for security issues.  If you download the script and read it, you're (more) protected against many vulnerabilities due to typo-squatting and malicious commands lurking on the internet.